# getting error:An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied while delete the file/folder from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

i wrote this piece of code for delete the files/folders from s3 bucket, getting below error
:An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied
Below is My code:

```
    def post(self, request):
    try:
        company_id = request.data.get('company_id')
        execute_function.get_connection_by_company(company_id)
        # filename = request.data.get('ip_file_name')
        s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_AccessKeyId,
                          aws_secret_access_key=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_SecretAccessKey)
        s3.delete_object(Bucket=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_NAME, Key='https://examplebucket123.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/regionfolder/031619-QA.jpg')

    except Exception as err:
        http_err = traceback.format_exc()
        print(http_err)
        return HttpResponse(http_err, status=500)
    finally:
        execute_function().close_db_connection()
```

Comment: Your access key credentials don't have DeleteObject permissions on your S3 bucket's objects, it's not related to Python but your IAM roles/policies.

Comment: @jarvis how can edit and where can i get policy code

Comment: You need to edit the permissions policy from the AWS account console where this bucket resides.